# Dynamic Pivot Table Sort by Month and year

Tags: sql-server

I have used dynamic pivot query using the script below.

```
    select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, createDate)))
                      FROM OSCL                        
    GROUP BY QUOTENAME(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, createDate)))
     , DATEPART(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, createDate))
    ORDER BY DATEPART(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, createDate))        
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');
```

I am getting the following result.

```
Description   January   February  March April 
xxxxxx           44       20        0    12
```

I want the following

```
Description   January 2017   February2017   March 2017  April 2017 
xxxxxx           44             20              0          12
```

Could you please suggest the script for this.

Thanking you,

Hem

Comment: You're only showing part of your script, so it's tough to determine if my answer will work for your desired results.

Answer (score 1):

This is one option:

It uses a subquery to get the date values but notice I've moved the ORDER BY clause out of the subquery.

> ```
> declare @dt table (mydate date);
> insert into @dt values ('20170101'),('20170201'),('20170301'),('20170401'),('20170501'),('20170601'),('20170701'),('20170801');
>
> declare @cols varchar(1000);
>
>
> select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(mn.[MonthName], '-', CAST(mn.[Year] AS VARCHAR(10))))
>                       FROM (SELECT YEAR(mydate) [Year], MONTH(mydate) [Month], DATENAME(MONTH, mydate) AS [MonthName] 
>                             FROM @dt 
>                             GROUP BY YEAR(mydate), MONTH(mydate), DATENAME(MONTH, mydate)) mn
>                 ORDER BY [Year],[Month]
>                       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
>                       ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') , 1, 1, '');
>
> select @cols;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name)                                                                                          |
> | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | [January-2017],[February-2017],[March-2017],[April-2017],[May-2017],[June-2017],[July-2017],[August-2017] |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=80a733813da57c26a19459ad57aab837)*

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you.

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, CreatedDateTime)) + ' ' + Cast(Year(CreatedDateTime) as varchar(4)))
                      FROM Customers_CVSTargetCab_AuditLog                        
    GROUP BY QUOTENAME(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, CreatedDateTime)) + ' ' +  Cast(Year(CreatedDateTime) as varchar(4)))
     , DATEPART(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, CreatedDateTime))
    ORDER BY DATEPART(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, CreatedDateTime))        
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');
```

Comment: I am sorry for not bringing the whole issue. This works party and if i use  this in the following Dynamic pivot script the result values are all NULL. I am  missing  something in the cast year function. Could you please suggest a change.

Comment: Without seeing the whole script, it's hard to suggest a solid answer.